# Apache FOP - Extra content at the end

Tags: pdf, apache-fop

I have a simple task, which I've found quite complex to implement with Apache FOP.
I have already created some layout. So I do have nice first page, only page, rest pages and last page definitions with well distributed content on it, but now I need sometimes add to the end of the document some extra content (like Terms and conditions, or Agreement conditions) which sometimes takes even few pages. That content shouldn't have any header, footer, page number etc... Just a text flow with paragraphs.

Thank you.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to FOP I haven't recognized well FOP capabilities posting my question here.

So I've sorted out the issue with new page-master and new page-sequence definitions.